# SSE Connection pending when reconnecting

Tags: javascript, html, server, client, server-sent-events

I have an SSE connection that I setup like this =>

```
  init(channel: string, reconnecting?: boolean) {
    if (this.eventSource) {
      return console.warn("SSE : Already Setup");
    }
    console.info("SSE Channel Start");

    this.channel = channel;
    this.eventSource = new EventSource(HTTPUtils.getPath(`${environment.SSE_PATH}?channel=${this.channel}`));

    this.eventSource.onopen = () => {
      console.info("SSE : Connection OPEN");
      this.state$.next(reconnecting ? SSEState.RECONNECTED : SSEState.CONNECTED);
    };

    this.eventSource.onerror = (error) => {
      console.info("SSE : Connection Lost", error);
      this.close();
      this.state$.next(SSEState.RECONNECTING);
      this.attemptReconnect();
    };
  }
```

now when the server drop, the connection get closed, and I would like to reconnect to the server when he gets back up again :

```
  private attemptReconnect() {
    if (this.retryIntervalRef) {
      return;
    }
    let timer = 0;
    this.retryIntervalRef = setInterval(() => {
      timer += 1000;
      if (timer > this.retryTimer) {
        this.init(this.channel, true);
        clearInterval(this.retryIntervalRef);
        this.retryIntervalRef = null;
      }
    }, 1000);
  }
```

The first connection is ok, when the server drop, this attemptReconnect is called. After 20 sec, it tries to reconnect, and the sse open, but it stays STUCK in pending :

[image]

When there is an error I reset everything to its initial state using

```
  close() {
    if (this.eventSource) {
      console.info("SSE Channel Closed");
      this.eventSource.close();
      this.eventSource = null;
      this.state$.next(SSEState.CLOSED);
      this.callbacks = new Map<string, (e: any) => void>();
    }
  }
```

and restart the same process... so I don't understand why the SSE remaining in a pending state.

EDIT INFO :

If I refresh before my app tries to reconnect, everything works fine. If I wait for the timer to end to reconnect, it will remain pending. I do not have access to the BE, so I wonder if it could also be a BE problem. Any idea would help me a lot thx!

Comment: can you confirm when you try to reconnect how many connections are in active state that are connected to the server.

Comment: I do not have access to the server sadly, but I will try to gather this intel.

Comment: you can check from dev tools when you are trying how many connections are created from the same tab where you are using your app.

Comment: check this [post](https://textslashplain.com/2019/12/04/the-pitfalls-of-eventsource-over-http-1-1/)

Answer (score 0):

It might be issue with the token you are passing while reconnecting.

Send a valid token when you reconnect.

What i can suggest in this case, before the server connection getting closed (say server close the connecter after 20 mins) from client side disconnect and reconnect for every 19 mins with a valid token.